# Deployment using image from scratch fails to start

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am building an image using the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:1.19.2-bullseye as builder

COPY src /src

WORKDIR /src

RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -race -ldflags "-s -w" -o client-go

FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /src/client-go /client-go

ENTRYPOINT [ "/client-go" ]
```

and creating the following `Deployment`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-skaffold
  name: test-skaffold
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-skaffold
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test-skaffold
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: pkaramol/test-skaffold
        name: test-skaffold
```

The deployment is done using `skaffold` FWIW.

The process fails as follows:

```
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/test-skaffold: container test-skaffold terminated with exit code 1
    - pod/test-skaffold-c955979f6-ckpqg: container test-skaffold terminated with exit code 1
      > [test-skaffold-c955979f6-ckpqg test-skaffold] standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
 - deployment/test-skaffold failed. Error: container test-skaffold terminated with exit code 1.
```

What is the failure cause?

#### Update

Changing the `FROM` in the 2nd build stage to `ubuntu` fixes things, but why is `scratch` failing to find the `ENTRYPOINT` ?

Comment: `scratch` isn't failing to find the entrypoint - it's because the executable has dynamic links to glibc amongst other things, and these `so` files aren't present on the filesystem.
```ldd /client-go
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc51c4000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f54b13df000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f54b120a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f54b1407000)
```

Comment: Note that if you compile with cgo disabled, this won't be an issue: ```ldd /client-go
        not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Ι am trying to build a statically linked binary but the end result is the same `go build -ldflags="-extldflags=-static" -o client-go`

Comment: It seems it needs **both** `CGO_ENABLED=0` and the above directive to build static binary (no idea why they are **both** needed)

Comment: @pkaramol Thank you for the solution on how to make the slimmiest `go` docker! Just 1.21 MB for *Hello, World!* go executable compared to 996 MB of the docker built from `go:latest`.

Comment: keep in mind you'll also need CA root certificates available if you want to make any TLS connections from Go - at least if you want to validate the certificates of those connections which you absolutely should want to do. You can generally copy those over as well

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept itfor the greater visibility of community